# Need to run R code on all text files in a folder

Tags: r, file

I have a text file. I made a R code for it to extract a certain line of information from it.

```
###Read file and format
txt_files <- list.files(pattern = '*.txt')
text <- lapply(txt_files, readLines)   
text <- sapply(text, function(x) iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))

###Search and store grep
l =grep("words" ,text)
(k<- length(l))

###Matrix to store data created
mat <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = k, ncol = 2)
nrow(mat)

###Main
for(i in 1:k){                                          
u= 1
while(text[(l[i])-u]!=""){
line.num=u;
u=u+1
}
mat[i,2]<-text[(l[i])-u-1]
mat[i,1]<- i
}   
###Write the output file
write.csv(mat, file = "Evalutaion.csv")
```

It runs on one file at a time. I need to run it on many files and append all the results in a single file with an additional column that tells me the name of the file from which each of the result has come. I am unable to come up with some solution. What changes do I make?

Comment: Unrelated, but the correct regex pattern is `pattern = '.+\\.txt$'`.

Comment: It is unclear what is expected end result, it would help your case if you show dummy input and output for one loop index. You could to edit your post and include output of `dput(head(text,5))` and `dput(head(mat,5))`

Answer (score 0):

Applying your operations to all files in a folder:

```
   txt_files <- list.files(pattern = '*.txt')

   # Applying all your functions on all txt_files using for loop, you need to use indexes inside where ever you are using txt_files
   for (i in 1:length(txt_files)) {
   # Operation 1
   # Operation 2
   # Operation 3

   write.table(mat,file=paste0("./",sub(".txt","",FILES[i]),".csv"),row.names=F,quote=F,sep=",")
   }
```

Merging files together with same headers, I have two csv files with Same Header `Data` and `Value`, File Names were `File1.csv` and `File2.csv` inside `Header` folder, which I am merging together to get one header and all rows and columns. Make sure both the files have same number of columns and same headers in same order.

```
## Read into a list of files, an Example below
 library(plyr)
 library(gdata)
 setwd("./Header")   # CSV Files to be merged are in this direcory
 ## Read into a list of files:
 filenames <- list.files(path="./",pattern="*.csv")
 fullpath=file.path("./",filenames)
 print (filenames)
 print (fullpath)
 dataset <- do.call("rbind",lapply(filenames,FUN=function(files){read.table(files,sep=",",header=T)}))
 dataset
#   Data Value
# 1  ABC    23
# 2  PQR    33
# 3  MNP    43       # Till here was File.csv
# 4   AC    24
# 5   PQ    34
# 6   MN    44       # Till here was File2.csv

write.table(dataset,file="dataset.csv",sep=",",quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)
```